# deallocate inactive view controller in tab bar controller

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have an application with 3 tabs in a tab bar controller, when you modify the values in a tab you have to recreate a graph in the other tabs with the new values, the graph only works well when you create the view from the principle so when changing the tab I would like to delete the view controller from memory and only keep active the one that is being viewed.
How can this be done?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Isn't that a bit like throwing out your car because the ash tray is full? You cannot delete a view controller from memory if it is part of a tab bar interface. And you don't need to. The user only sees the graph when the user switches to that view controller, so just _refresh_ the graph when the user switches to that view controller.

Comment: El problema es que cuando cambian los datos en el carrito esto se rompió, tengo otro hilo con esto.    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47489210/is-there-any-way-to-reset-the-barchart

Comment: So you are just re-asking your own question. Please do NOT do that. Do not duplicate your own question. If your question has not gotten any answers, edit it. Do not waste bandwidth by repeating it as a separate question.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47489210/is-there-any-way-to-reset-the-barchart

Comment: I do not consider it as duplicating the question, just another way of doing or solving the problem that does not have to do intrinsically with the graphic, I thought that if I download the memory screen and upload it again it is an imaginative way to sort out the problem, that's why I opened another thread. However I am sorry if you consider that I have duplicated the thread :(

Answer (score 1):

You can set `view` of `UIViewController` to `nil` `self.view = nil` what will lead to restart of lifecycle. So when you will switch `tabBarController` back to this `viewController` it will call `viewDidLoad` method of that `UIViewController`

Comment: Amazing, works perfectly. Thanks very much :) the view is reset whit this simple line :)

Comment: That's bad behavior. You get a proper event, `viewWillAppear`. That is the place to do your reset, whatever that consists of. Unloading the view controller's view is wrong.

Comment: @matt TC ask how to remove `UIViewController` from `UITabBarController`. However it is not possible, I showed him how to unload this `UIViewController`. I'm not agree with you what setting `view` to `nil` it's a bad behavior. It is very useful when you need to decrease memory usage in you app, for example when you have a lot `UIViewController`'s in `UINavigationController`.

Comment: No, it's not very useful. If you find yourself having to set a view controller's `view` to `nil`, you're doing something wrong. It's a Bad Smell, not a solution.

Comment: then how can i reset the barcharcontroller? Matt you mark my cuestion like a duplicate but no is a duplicate, this is another cuestion whit another solution. please can yoy dismark the other cuestion like duplicate? thank